# Asymptotic behavior of a solution of an ODE

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations, asymptotics

I am not quite sure if this question is appropriate for this site as it might be not of a research level. 
I am interested in the following ordinary differential equation on the real line
$$f’’(x)+(x-a)f(x)=0$$
where $a>0$.

> Is it possible to solve it explicitly? or using say hypergeometric functions? In any case, I would be interested to know asymptotic behavior  of solutions when $x\to +\infty$.

Comment: Maple performs its general solution $f \left( x \right) ={\it \_C1}\,{{\rm Ai}\left(-x+a\right)}+{\it \_C2}
\,{{\rm Bi}\left(-x+a\right)}
 $ in terms of the Airy functions (see https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Airy&term=Airy for more info). Maple also finds its asymptotics at $\infty$. I think allthat is well known. Indeed, this is not a question at the research level.

Comment: Up a time translation and inversion, $t=-x+a$ it is Airy's equation $u''(t)+tu(t)=0$, whose 2 linearly independent solutions (with initial data $(u(0),u'(0) = (0,1)$ resp $(1,0)$ ), have a very simple entire power series expansion. Check  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function for info, included the asymptotics.

Comment: For the record: WolframAlpha also [does the job](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%27%27%5Bx%5D%2B%28x-a%29f%5Bx%5D%3D%3D0), free of charge.

Comment: @Mateusz Kwaśnicki: But not the required asymptotics. Free WA is not very strong.

Comment: @user64494: Of course, you are right. On the other hand, it is [not as bad as it seems](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Series%5BAi%5Bx%5D,%7Bx,Infinity,2%7D%5D). And once you know the name of the solution, it is quite straightforward to look up the property you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to solve it explicitly in terms of the Airy function.
Airy's equation in the standard form is
$$y''=xy.$$
Your equation is reduced to this by $x\mapsto-x$ followed by a shift of the independent variable.
Airy functions have been thoroughly studied and almost everything you want to know about them is known. In particular there is a full asymptotic expansion for them as $x\to\infty$. Your question is about the behavior of Airy function as $x\to-\infty$. It oscillates, has infinitely may zeros, and the shape of this oscillation is very well described in the special function handbooks.
Airy function can be obtained from a hypergeometric one by a confluence process.
 Type "Airy functions" on Google.